# How do I stop form fields jumping when a select option is selected?

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, css-tables

I am trying to create a contact form which has several fields.  When someone chooses that their query is about being interested in a class I have a piece of Javascript that pops out a radio field that asks them what level they are.  The trouble is that when this happens all the fields jump over to the right and the radio buttons don't all fit on one line like they did before I had the Javascript.

[image: Page View As It Should Be]

[image: Page View When "Interested In Class" is selected]

Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```js
 function showfield(name) {
   if (name == 'Interested In Class') document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML = '<div id="form-group"> <label for="level">Level Of English:</label> <input name="level" type="radio" id="level" required>Beginner<input name="level" type="radio" id="level" required>Intermediate<input name="level" type="radio" id="level" required>Advanced</div>';
   else document.getElementById('reveal').innerHTML = '';
 }
```

```css
/* Forms */

form {
  display: table;
}
#form-group {
  display: table-row;
}
#form-group label:after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: super;
}
label {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: table-cell;
}
input[type=text] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: solid #047BFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
  border: solid #5BD2FF;
}
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border: solid #047BFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: table-cell;
}
select:focus {
  border: solid #5BD2FF;
}
input[type=radio] {
  margin: 8px 0;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 16px;
  display: table-cell;
}
#comments {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentOS">
  <form name="contact" method="post" action="#" class="contentcontact">
    <div id="form-group">
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" required>
    </div>
    <div id="form-group">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
      <input name="lastName" type="text" id="lastName" required>
    </div>
    <div id="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div id="form-group">
      <label for="query">Select Your Query:</label>
      <select name="query" type="radio" id="query" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" required>
        <option></option>
        <option value="Interested In Class">I'm interested in joining a class</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="reveal"></div>
    <div id="form-group">
      <label for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <input name="comments" type="text" id="comments" required>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is that the `<div id="form-group">` is not enclosing the `<div id="reveal">`

Append your html code with this,

```
<div id="form-group">

       <label for="query">Select Your Query:</label>
       <select name="query" type="radio" id="query" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" required>
        <option></option>
        <option value="Interested In Class">I'm interested in joining a class</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
       </select>
       <!-- this is where the </div> was wrongly placed -->
       <div id="reveal"></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: So this sort of works but when the "Level of English" bit appears it appears under the input fields not under the rest of the labels.  I don't want the reveal div to be included in the select form-group div as it is its own separate form-group for "Level of English" which is in the javascript code.